# How to put 'tk.' in front of every Tkinter object the right way?

Tags: python, tkinter, readability

I threw together a very quick proof of concept python application (~1000 lines) and it now has potential to be taken more seriously.  It says for best programming practices, don't use

```
from <module> import *
```

(I did this for the proof of concept) Because I use Tkinter and ttk (plus a few more), I figured I'd just go back and quickly add 'tk.' in front of my buttons/labels/etc.  The problem is, I have a lot of sticky commands and putting tk.N tk.S tk.E tk.W for every Tkinter keyword would take a while and doesn't seem like that's how it should be (readability would be gross for the longer commands).

Is there some trick?  Should I do something like the following?

```
from Tkinter import N S E W
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You are just missing a comma.  Like this: `from tkinter import N, S, E, W`

Comment: This'll come down to opinion, but tk.N isn't that many more characters than N and N won't be an intuitive variable to someone looking at your code later, IMO. I would assume N is the dimension of the image of something, or a loop limit, not the word 'north'. Also note you could use a string there, tk accepts that. Although I guess sticky=N couldn't mean too many things, just seems like asking for trouble

Comment: You seem to be asking "how do I do an `from tkinter import *` without doing that. You can't have it both ways. You can, however, do `import tkinter as tk; from tkinter import N, E, S, W` which brings most into the `tk` namespace (`tk.Button`) with while N is in the global namespace. That said, members with names of one character are far more readable as `tk.N` than `N`.

Comment: @en_Knight: The Tkinter names N,S,E,W _are_ actually directions, used for widget alignment. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: @PM2Ring I know, I'm just saying it seems like an easy way to confuse future readers. It's a fine identifier when prepended with the namespace, and probably isn't amiguous here (maybe it's just a gut reaction to seeing a one letter variable name). I agree with bryan's suggestion: sticky='n' seems preferable to me than sticky=N.

Comment: @en_Knight: Fair enough. I was _almost_ going to suggest just using string literals instead, but then I figured that `tk.N` is only one char more than `'n'`. :) FWIW, I always use the `tk.N` form in my Tkinter code, just to keep things explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to not use `N`, `S`, `E` and `W` (eg: `x.grid(..., sticky="nsew")`). Just use the literal strings. The constants aren't going to change -- they've been the same since 1996 and the tcl/tk community takes backwards compatibility very seriously.